# How to manage the copyright notice for a composite document?

Tags: bibliographies, glossaries, indexing

I'm creating several documents in which different sections come from different sources and thus have potentially different copyright notices.  I'd like all copyright notices to appear in one place (identified with a `\copyrightnotice` or equivalent command) with nothing visible in the text (to avoid interrupting the flow of the document) and with each section a copyright notices applies to properly identified in a description list-like format.

Since sections might be swapped in or out between documents, I don't want to have to manage the contents of this list myself, but rather have a command identifying the copyright of a source inside the file that contains the source with the contents of these commands collected and then printed automatically in the identified location (something like a bibliography list or glossary).  Ideally, however, copyright notices should not be duplicated but rather, if two sections share the same copyright notice, they should be listed together.  Something like:

```
Section 1: ©2020 Foo Inc.
Section 2, Section 4: ©2019 Bar Co.
Section 3: ©2012 ABC Foundation
```

My research into glossaries, bibliographies, indices, and the like haven't revealed a package that does exactly what I want it to do (most aren't setup to identify by section, and list consolidation doesn't work as I'd like), but perhaps I've missed something or misunderstood the way various packages work.  Does anyone have any suggestions for which package might be the best for approaching this problem?

Comment: I cannot answer the question as-asked, but: In many places around the world, the copyright page is expected to contain (at minimum) certain information. Were you going to leave it blank at the notice? It would be better to put a generic "Portions of this work are obtained from various sources, with different copyrights. The individual copyrights are displayed where material is used." Or something like that.

Comment: @rallg I think you misunderstood what I was asking.  I'm trying to consolidate all the copyright notices into one place, the copyright page, rather than having them scattered throughout the document.  The issue is that in terms of the sources, it makes sense for each source to identify where it comes from (as it is used, so unused sources don't appear on the copyright page) and for the typesetting engine to collect, place, and format that information appropriately.

Comment: Yes, I did misunderstand. Got it backwards.